# jQueryUI Dialog + Firefox + ASP.Net = access to strict mode caller function is censored

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page that works great in IE and Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox and Opera. When I say it doesn't work I mean that the `Submit` button doesn't do anything at all. It is a page with several nested `UpdatePanels` on it and a couple of jQueryUI Accordions on it too.

I have a simple `div`.

```
<div id="date-dialog" title="Date?">
    <label id="lblDate" for="txtDate">
        Please Enter Your The Date:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="txtDate" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</div>
```

And then I have some simple code to turn it into a dialog:

```
$('#date-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function () {
            __doPostBack('DateButton', $('#txtDate').val());
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$('#txtDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

I've also tried adding this, which doesn't help and which actually doesn't work with a modal dialog:

```
    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    },
```

In Firefox I get the following error:

```
Error: TypeError: access to strict mode caller function is censored
Source File: http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/2/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js
Line: 718
```

I have no idea what to do to fix this. I would love to turn off `strict mode`, but I can't find any information on how to do that. I can barely find any information about that error using Google. It seems like what I'm doing should be quite simple.

Comment: I have create a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166951/the-aspnet-ajax-scripts-are-incompatible-with-use.html) about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't actually explain how to fix the problem, this is a working work-around.

I created a hidden field that corresponded to each field in the dialog box. Then I created a button. These had to be kept outside of the dialog box `div` because the `div` is moved to outside the form when it is turned in to a dialog box. Then I modified my dialog box creation code to be something like this:

```
$('#date-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function () {
            $('#<%=hfDate.ClientID %>').val($('#txtDate').val());
            $('#<%=btnFormSubmit.ClientID %>').click();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I suddenly see the same problem (don't know why, it worked before). As you mentioned in your question, the JavaScript code behind `__doPostBack('DateButton', '');` throws the error. Changed it to `$('#<%=DateButton.ClientID %>').click();` and it works again ... looks like a bug in the ASP.NET JavaScript to me.

Answer (score 33):

This is kind of an old post, but this issue still occurred to me today.
I didn't wanted to use the click of the button, so instead i tried a `setTimeout` and it also works.

To people having this issue, try this solution:

```
setTimeout(function() { __doPostBack('DateButton', $('#txtDate').val()); }, 1);
```

Comment: Had this problem with Firefox 46, and a bootbox.confirm() callback. Adding the setTimeout above fixed it in a jiff. Thanks.

Comment: Firefox 58.0.2 as well. What are the implications -- and why does this even work? Update: I found some information about why this works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36867843/12919

Answer (score 5):

Having recently had to address this issue I found that I could solve the problem and get __doPostBack working in Edge, IE, Chrome & FireFox by adding the following script to the top of my app.

```
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) { window.event = {}; }
```

Using the *SetTimeout* function breaks Edge.  Just putting in *window.event={}* broke IE.

Comment: Absolutely works in my experience, and easily the simplest fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is working for IE, Chrome and Firefox. browser!, Thanks to https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2016/02/12/wtf-microsoftajax-js-vs-use-strict-vs-firefox-vs-ie/

```
function hackEventWithinDoPostBack() {
var originalEventDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Window.prototype, "event");
    var hackEventVariable = false;
    var eventPropertyHolder;
    Object.defineProperty(window, "event", {
        configurable: true,
        get: function get() {
            var result = originalEventDescriptor ? originalEventDescriptor.get.apply(this, arguments) : eventPropertyHolder;
            if (result || !hackEventVariable)
                return result;
            return {};
        },
        set: function set(value) {
            if (originalEventDescriptor)
                originalEventDescriptor.set.apply(this, arguments);
            else
                eventPropertyHolder = value;
        }
    });
    var originalDoPostBack = window.__doPostBack;

    window.__doPostBack = function hackedDoPostBack() {
        hackEventVariable = true;
        originalDoPostBack.apply(this, arguments);
        hackEventVariable = false;
    };
}

hackEventWithinDoPostBack();
```

Comment: You should credit the original source of this, which is https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2016/02/12/wtf-microsoftajax-js-vs-use-strict-vs-firefox-vs-ie/

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in Firefox Quantum. I was using a jQuery 3.x CDN, I had to download it to reference it locally in my project. After that I edited it (jquery.3.x.min.js) and commented/removed the following:

`"use strict";`

I had to do a `search` to remove them all. There were two.

Answer (score 0):

This might be some good news but I am unable to replicate the problem in the latest Firefox 84.0.2 and jQuery 3.5.1. I tested the reported scenario plus other __doPostBack problematic scenarios related to the 'use strict' rule and all of them seem to work without any JS errors.

Do you still experience this issue with the latest jQuery 3.5.1 and latest Firefox 84.0.2?

There is also an official statement from jQuery team but it is old and applies to jQuery 1.9.1, but not 3.5.1 - https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13335.

Thank you!