# The cause for TypeError: access to strict mode caller function censoered

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm working on a web application that uses the JMol Javascript extension with Angular. This is challenging. It's been working quite well, but today it stopped working on Firefox. When I try something JMol complains with the error

> TypeError: access to strict mode caller function censored

This is happening in 3rd party code, only on Firefox (which has updated itself yesterday). It works well on Chrome.

I found some people complaining about a similar error over the years (without using JMol). They all received interesting answers - downgrading jQuery to 1.1, wrapping some function call in `setTimeout` and other such answers.

I could not find an explanation for the cause of this error. What is a strict mode caller, which access is censored, and why? I would also love to see a minimal piece of code that generates this error on Firefox - so I can understand what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Can you check :- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1170139  , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533585/jqueryui-dialog-firefox-asp-net-access-to-strict-mode-caller-function-is-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that code that tries to use the `caller` property of a function is being called by strict-mode code. Example:

```js
function attemptToUseCaller() {
    console.log(attemptToUseCaller.caller.name);
}
function loose() {
    attemptToUseCaller();
}

function strict() {
    "use strict";
    attemptToUseCaller();
}
loose();
strict();
```

If you run that in an up-to-date version of Firefox, you'll see this in the console:

```
loose
TypeError: access to strict mode caller function is censored
```

As you can see, accessing `attemptToUseCaller.caller` worked when the calling function was in loose mode, but failed when the calling function was in strict mode. Accessing the `caller` property is disallowed in strict mode, and even disallowed when used in "loose" code, if the caller function is itself strict. Firefox raises a specific error, whereas with Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine, it just returns the value `null` for `.caller` in strict mode.

Using [`caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) is an anti-pattern. You'll need to fork whatever 3rd-party code is using it and correct it.

Comment: OK, got it, thanks. Changing the 3rd-party code is going to be a real pain, as it's partly Javascript code that was automatically generated from Java.

Comment: @zmbq - Fun fun fun... :-)

Comment: Fortunately I found a site that seems to have a working version of JMol - probably an older version. I'll try to downgrade and hope for the best...