# Function __doPostBack() does not work in iOS, iPadOS browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, asp.net, browser, dopostback

I'm developing an ASP.NET Webform website using .NET Framework 4.6, C# and Javascript,

I've used HiddenField to store a value from a navigation drawer, then do a postback to update value in UpdatePanel, but seem that the code stucked at __doPostBack() on iOS, iPadOS browsers (all Safari, Chrome, Firefox), for Windows browsers everything works fine. Below is my Javascript code:

```
function headChange(e) {
   __doPostBack('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>', '');
};
```

I tried several methods found on Internet such as:

- Added `<browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="256"/>` in web.config
- Added `return false;` after `__doPostBack('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>', '');`
- Replace `__doPostBack('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>', '');` by `<%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(HiddenField1, String.Empty) %>;`
- Added a browser file to App_Browsers folder

but all with no luck,

Has anyone encountered the same problem and found the solution for this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: open yours browsers debug info and see what errors do you have on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error by do  Inspect Element in Sarari, the error is shown as follow:

https://ibb.co/ynL1Zhp

"Function.caller used to retrieve strict caller" cause by __doPostBack function in MicrosoftAjaxWebforms.js

Then I found the solution for this by https://stackoverflow.com/a/25686598/7819116

Now my website works well in iOS browsers

Thank you all for the supports!